# How to remove all rows based on a particular column in R?

Tags: r, csv, apply

I have a csv file as

Where the headers are

```
Id,Name,State
```

Data.csv

```
Id,Name,State
23,Fred,California
56,Sam,Texas
78,Renee,Washington
56,Walter,California
```

Desired output

```
Id,Name,State
56,Sam,Texas
78,Renee,Washington
```

I have read the information as

```
 record <- read.csv("Data.csv",header=TRUE)
 State <- record$State
```

I want to remove all rows containing "California" as the "State" value.

New to R. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you loaded the csv into a data frame called `df`:

```
df[df$State != "California", ]
```

You might want to check out this ref card: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf

*Edit*

With regards to your update:

```
record <- read.table(sep=",", header=T, text="
Id,Name,State
23,Fred,California
56,Sam,Texas
78,Renee,Washington
56,Walter,California")
State <- record$State

record[record$State != "California", ]
#   Id  Name      State
# 2 56   Sam      Texas
# 3 78 Renee Washington

State[State != "California"]
# [1] Texas      Washington
# Levels: California Texas Washington

record[State != "California", ]
#   Id  Name      State
# 2 56   Sam      Texas
# 3 78 Renee Washington
```

Comment: I have modified the question, the above method did not work,thanks and any further help is appreciated.

Comment: I put some more examples into my post